# Flutter GetX RxList assign issue

Tags: flutter, assign, flutter-getx

Im trying to convert old code to new code syntax. I have a issue with RxList.

[image]

So I change **postModel.assign(postDetail);**

[image]

But In my news_detail page How I can access to value?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you shouldn''t use `postModel` as a List as your API clearly returns a single post (NewsModel) by id and not a list of post (List of NewsModel). So using `var postModel = <NewsModel>[].obs;` is totally unnecessary in my opinion.
What you could do is:

```
final postModel = NewsModel().obs;
```

And then on API call:

```
postModel.value = postDetail;
```

And then on View:

```
Image.network(controller.postModel.value.imageUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

`postModel` is a `List`.

So you would need to access an item in that list, using an `int` index.

Something like this:

```
return Image.network(newsDetailController.postModel[0].imageUrl);
```